# Upload something a running file in php

Tags: java, php, upload

I know it sounds strange. I've a php file on my server which is responsible for handling uploads. And a java program on my desktop sends files to this php file. I want to cancel the file upload process to the server whenever I want. So I want to create a kind of stream or something like that to stop ongoing upload process.

I tried to use PIDs to stop a php file's running. But a php file doesn't start running before the client finished uploading.

I want to run the "savePid()" function before the upload started. So I can get the PID and stop running of the file whenever I want.

```
<?php
include('func.php');
savePid(); //run this before upload started

$in = stream_get_contents(fopen("php://input", "rb"));
$out = fopen('pipeupload.txt', 'w');

while ( ! feof($in) ) {
    fwrite($out, fread($in, 8192));
}
?>
```

I know this won't work. I'm just looking for a solution to stop an ongoing upload process.

Comment: I don't think you can stop upload from PHP. As far as I know PHP gets the file once the upload is finished. The real receive process is done by your web server.

Comment: @bansi I can choose another solution on the server side. I just need to stop uploading process.

Comment: If you cancel the upload of the java program in the java program, PHP will receive only a partial upload. Check for that error and let the script die.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I know I've to stop the process on the server.

Comment: Killing a web server process is **not** a good idea as it can lead to more problems than it solves. Also this will probably not even stop the upload itself. Stop the upload on the clientside.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I've been searching for 2 days and still not found a solution. I also talked to my server company and they don't know how to do this. Probably I will have to do it on the cliendside but I don't understand what are these problems this kind of thing can lead?

Comment: Question : I've a php file on my server which is responsible for handling uploads. And a java program on my desktop sends files to this php file. ----> It means your java program provide path of upload file to php file. right ?

Comment: @Monty yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

**It might be possible on server side.**

**Example :**

> You have 20 images, every image is more than 2 mb in size. Your java
>   file from desktop send array of url's of images which is ready to
>   upload by php file as you told. In the php file you have to do some
>   change, before every image upload you have to check in database
>   (create table and add new field image_cancel or add this field in your
>   prev table, set default value is false) column name image_cancel is
>   true/false. if it true then stop execution and exit. Now create a new
>   script cancel_image.php ---> Write code inside and set image_cancel
>   field true.

Comment: Think I have just one image but it's 100 mb and I want to cancel uploading before it has been completely sent to the server.

Comment: the only solution I can think is to split a large file into small pieces and send them one by one and check if the server still wants to get the file after each piece has been sent.

Comment: @charty : YES for a big size image, you have to split image in small pieces,  you can do it using javascript also. I hope my answer is near to your answer.

Comment: you said I should send the paths of the images to the server and php will upload images. How can PHP upload a file with only path information? According to your answer, java program will send the path of the file instead of the file itself? or I don't understand :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy thing to do.

There are couple of options I can think of, but both are not easy. Easier first

**First Method:**
You should have 2 PHP scripts one for handling the upload (which you have now) and another to notify the client to abort. The client should upload to the upload script as you are doing now, and also regularly check if an abort is posted at the notify script. Once the client finds abort it aborts the rest of the upload. Thus your file never reaches the PHP file handling the upload. This method requires the client to handle the abort. A client not respecting the abort still can upload the full file.

**Second Method:**
You should write your own file handling module or application instead of the normal web server. You can also write apache module which hooks into file upload (if your web server is apache). But this method is more complex and will not run on web servers if you are not hosting it. This method requires patching the webserver or installing application working at system level, and I don't think any administrator will allow this on their server.